# Laravel Access the public folder of other Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory

I am trying to build the admin panel in Laravel for a live website that is also in Laravel. I want to access the public folder of another Laravel project.

I tried this code:

```
public static function CustomerPublic(string $string)
    {
        if(env('APP_ENV')=='local'){
            return __DIR__.'/custom_dir/'.$string; 
        }
    }
```

The issue I am facing: It starts the file with root-like **127.0.0.1**

I am looking for a way to access the dir of another laravel project from the current project.

Edit:
My Dir structure

```
return __DIR__.'/../../../web_vue/public/'.$string;
```

Result I got:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/alihyder/7E74636D746326DD/Projects/PatientCare/web_vue/public/uploads/images/banner_1.jpg
```

Result I want:

file:///media/alihyder/7E74636D746326DD/Projects/PatientCare/web_vue/public/uploads/images/banner_1.jpg

Comment: what is your folder structure ? put screen shot does both r in same ? `dir` like `oneproject` and `anothproject` ?

Comment: Yes both projects in one folder like  adminapnel and usersite

Comment: try this `base_path('../adminapnel/public')` from `oneproject` this project

Comment: it's also leading with  127.0.0.1

Comment: ohh u need asset `url` not `path` for that you need to add new key in `.env` like `OTHER_URL=http://your project name`  then you need to use like `return env('OTHER_URL').'/custom_dir/'.$string; `

Comment: then how i can apply CRUD operation on it?

Answer (score 1):

```
APP_URL=http://your project name
```

add on .env file

Comment: how it will work with uploading file to that dir? Like i want to apply crud operations also on that public folder.

Comment: DocumentRoot  /var/www/html/your project name/public

Comment: add this path on your directory

Comment: not working. I tried you can check my edit question.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom variable in your .env file
e.g:

`CUSTOM_URL=https://admin.somewebsite.com`

and then use that url like:

`env("CUSTOM_URL")`

Comment: how it will work with uploading file to that dir? Like i want to apply crud operations also on that public folder.

Comment: well if you want the same database records on the both projects, then in `.env` configuration setup same configuration of mysql for both projects and if you want media content on other projects, then store the images in database like `/storage/uploads/image.jpeg` instead of `https://admin.somethig.com/storage/uploads/image.jpeg` and then in your other projects you can just access it like `{{env('CUSTOM_URL').$product->image}}` something like that.

Comment: CRUD is applyable from both end. like user can also edit/delete public/uploads folder files and admin can also edit/delete public/uploads folder files the folder

Answer (score 0):

as you need url of other project not `path`

you need to create new url in `.env`

like

```
OTHER_URL=http://your project name
```

then

```php
public static function CustomerPublic(string $string)
{
  if(env('APP_ENV')=='local'){
     return env('OTHER_URL').'/custom_dir/'.$string; 
  }
}
```

Comment: public_path access the public folder of current project only I want to access the folder that is in another project

Comment: then you need generate folder path based on your folder structure can u show me so i can write code for u

Answer (score 0):

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/  command type on your terminal

sudo cp 000-default.conf laravelproject.com.conf

sudo nano local-laravel-master.com.conf

after opening screen add all this hosting name

ServerName [www.local-laravelproject.com](http://www.local-laravelproject.com)
ServerAlias [www.local-laravelmaster.com](http://www.local-laravelmaster.com)
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel-master/public